# Android MVVM with servicelocator

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mvvm

Im trying to make mvvm pattern with repository and servicelocator to use mock's or remote calls, it depends on flavour.
What happening now,is that my liveData is not updating after i receive response from server. So for now i always have a empty list.

I use this google sample to trying make it.
[sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples)

My code below, using remote serviceLocator
Appreciate your help.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private val viewModel = TestViewModel(ServiceLocator.provideTasksRepository())
private lateinit var  binding : TestBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.test)
    binding.viewmodel = viewModel

    setupRecyclerView()
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    binding.viewmodel?.run {
        binding.recyclerViewTest.adapter = TestAdapter(this)
    }
}
```

}

```
class TestAdapter(private val viewModel : TestViewModel) : ListAdapter<ResponseEntity, TestAdapter.TestViewHolder>(TestDiffCallback()) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = TestViewHolder.from(parent)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(viewModel, item)
}

class TestViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemTestBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(viewModel: TestViewModel, item: ResponseEntity) {

        binding.viewmodel = viewModel
        binding.game = item
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): TestViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

            return TestViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" />

    <variable
        name="game"
        type="com.test.ResponseEntity" />

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.test.TestViewModel" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_test"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:items="@{viewmodel.items}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
class MyRepository(private val testRemoteDataSource: IDataSource) :
ITestRepository {

override suspend fun getList() = testRemoteDataSource.getList()
```

}

```
class TestViewModel(private val testRepository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {

private var _items = MutableLiveData<List<ResponseEntity>>()
val items: LiveData<List<ResponseEntity>> = _items

init {
    refreshList()
}

private fun refreshList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _items = testRepository.getList()
    }
}
```

}

```
object ServiceLocator {

var testRepository: MyRepository? = null

fun provideTasksRepository(): MyRepository {
    synchronized(this) {
        return testRepository ?: createTestRepository()
    }
}

private fun createTestRepository(): MyRepository {
    val newRepo = MyRepository(
        MyRemoteDataSource(RetrofitClient.apiInterface)
    )
    testRepository = newRepo
    return newRepo
}
```

}

```
class MyRemoteDataSource(private val retroService: IService) :
IDataSource {

private var responseEntityLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<ResponseEntity>> =
    MutableLiveData<List<ResponseEntity>>()

override suspend fun getGames(): MutableLiveData<List<ResponseEntity>> {

    retroService.getList()
        .enqueue(object : Callback<List<ResponseEntity>> {
            override fun onFailure(
                call: Call<List<ResponseEntity>>,
                t: Throwable
            ) {
                responseEntityLiveData.value = emptyList()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<ResponseEntity>>,
                response: Response<List<ResponseEntity>>
            ) {
                responseEntityLiveData.value = response.body()
            }
        })

    return responseEntityLiveData
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that mixing Coroutines suspending function with Retrofit and LiveData leads to some side effect here.

I do not have a single solution, but some points they can help you.

In general I would avoid mixing LiveData with suspending functions. LiveData is concept of caching data for the UI/ViewModel layer. Lower layers do not need to know anything like Android concrete stuff like LiveData. [More information here](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730)

In your repository or dataSource can either use a suspending function that returns a single value or Coroutines Flow that can emit more than one value. In your ViewModel you can then map those results to your LiveData.

**DataSource**

In your DataSource you can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to connect Retrofit (or any other callback interface) with Coroutines:

```kotlin
class DataSource(privat val retrofitService: RetrofitService) {

    /**
     * Consider [Value] as a type placeholder for this example
     */
    fun suspend fun getValue(): Result<Value> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
      retrofitService.getValue().enqueue(object : Callback<Value> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ResponseEntity>>,
                               throwable: Throwable) {
          continuation.resume(Result.Failure(throwable)))
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ResponseEntity>>,
                                response: Response<List<ResponseEntity>>) {
          continuation.resume(Result.Success(response.body()))
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**Result Wrapper**

You can wrap the response to your own `Result` type like:

```kotlin
sealed class Result<out T> {

    /**
     * Indicates a success state.
     */
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()

    /**
     * Indicates an error state.
     */
    data class Failure(val throwable: Throwable): Result<Nothing>
}
```

*I leave the Repository out from this example and call directly the DataSource.*

**ViewModel**

Now in your `ViewModel` you can launch the coroutine, getting the `Result` and map it to the LiveData.

```kotlin
class TestViewModel(private val dataSource: DataSource) : ViewModel() {
    private val _value = MutableLiveData<Value>>()
    val value: LiveData<Value> = _value

    private val _error = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val error: LiveData = _error

    init {
        getValue()
    }

    private fun getValue() {
      viewModelScope.launch {
        val result: Result<Value> = dataSource.getValue()
        
        // check wether the result is of type Success or Failure
        when(result) {
          is Result.Success -> _value.postValue(result.data)
          is Result.Failure -> _error.value = throwable.message
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: It works and seems a better solution that i gave. Maybe my fault to not understood the sample well. Thanks